# C++ code for Delphi `in` set operator

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I could not fully understand set membership in the help files. Please explain how `in` is handled in C++ for the following code:

```
if s1[1] in['0'..'9'] then
begin
  ii := StrToInt(s1)+1;
  s1 := IntToStr(ii);
  if Length(s1)<2 then s1 := '0'+s1;
  Edit_deneyismi.text := copy(s,1,i)+s1;
end
else Edit_deneyismi.text := 'Yeni_Deney_01';
```

Comment: What's wrong with `if (s1[1] >= '0' && s1[1] <= '9') {` ? (the index should perhaps be 0 in C++, I don't remember if indices are zero-based or one-based in Pascal).

Comment: Delphi strings are 1-based by default in desktop compilers, and 0-based by default in mobile compilers. There is a compiler directive to change that behavior.  C++Builder has not been updated to support mobile development yet, but that is [coming soon](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/davidi/2013/11/26/43019), so its VCL strings are still 1-based, but its C/C++ strings are 0-based.

Answer (score 4):

Delphi sets are implemented in C++Builder using the `Set<>` template class, which has a `Contains()` method to support `in` operations, eg:

```
Set<char, '0', '9'> Digits;
for (char c = '0'; c <= '9'; ++c)
    Digits << c;
```

```
if (Digits.Contains(s1[1]))
{
    ii = StrToInt(s1)+1;
    s1 = IntToStr(ii);
    if (s1.Length() < 2) s1 = "0" + s1;
    Edit_deneyismi->Text = s.SubString(1, i) + s1;
}
else
    Edit_deneyismi->Text = "Yeni_Deney_01";
```

Otherwise, use the C `isdigit()` function, or the RTL `Character::IsDigit()` function.  Or just compare the `char` values manually like Michael suggested.